# How to keep a git sub/feature branch sync with a master branch using rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

There is a master branch called `develop`. And a branch (`feature_branch_1`) originated from the develop branch. I'm making changes in the `feature_branch_1`. Let's say I will work on `feature_branch_1` for two weeks.
And each day I need my `feature_branch_1` synced up with the develop branch changes (`develop` branch will have changes committed by 
others and I need to have those changes, so that my `feature_branch_1` will not be much deviated from the `develop` branch and I know what is happening in `develop` branch as well)

I tried to use `git rebase develop` for this purpose as below,

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature_branch_1
git rebase develop
```

At first it was fine but when I made more changes to the `feature_branch_1` **rebasing will introduce more conflicts**. (It says *my own commits conflicts with each other*, It's **may be means that two of my commits modified the same line in the same file, and Git doesn't know which change to apply**) And resolving that is pretty much difficult and time consuming.

***Am I doing it wrong using rebase***? How can I keep my `feature_branch_1` synced up with the `develop` branch always(least need to be synced up with latest changes within past 24 hours)

**NOTE :** 
I checked other related SO questions also. Without using rebase at all we can do that. like below,

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout feature_branch_1
git merge develop
```

and after that,

```
git push origin/feature_branch_1
```

I can do this each day and keep my `feature_branch_1` synced with `develop`. ***Is there any way to do this with `rebase` without my own commits conflicting with each other ?***

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't avoid this when rebasing.  The long answer is that yes, you might be able to somewhat avoid this by just using `git merge` instead of rebase.  However, roughly speaking the friction between your `develop` and `feature_branch_1` branches will always be there, and should manifest itself regardless of the workflow you choose to use.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So then it might not a good idea to use rebase for syncing purpose.

Comment: Not at all, actually I prefer rebasing to merging for many reasons.  But synching would be a bit more technically complex, you would have to get good at rebasing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what do you mean by "you would have to get good at rebasing", in this case it is about conflict handling though, is there anyway to overcome that by using rebase.

Comment: When you rebase `feature_branch_1` on `develop`, then _every_ commit you made since divergence will have to be reapplied, and there could be conflicts with _each_ commit.  If you merge on the other hand, then there would be a single merge commit, and set of conflicts.  You should tend to see the same conflicts either way, but in the case of rebasing it could be spread out, and therefore possibly more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right to use it. The conflict files amount is depended on the changes of related commits. If both `develop` and `feature_branch_1` are changed many files, there maybe have more conflicts.
There is another way to do the same thing:

```
git checkout feature_branch_1
git pull origin develop --rebase
```

This will make your `feature_branch_1` based on the newest `develop` branch.

If your `feature_branch_1` has many commits after the last sync with develop branch, you can squash these commits before this time synchronization so that the commit history is more clear.

To use rebase or merge it depended whether you need to contribute for the main project. rebase just make you work on the newest develop branch and merge can make our work as part of the main project.